# How to send authentication token in http header with desired key value pairing in angular-4.0.0?

Tags: java, angular, rest, angular4-httpclient

I want to send authentication token in my http header to connect to my backend rest-api written in java.

From angular side the code is like(service.ts):

```
    getDataFromBackend() {
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      //this.getAuthToken() retrives auth token from cookies
      headers.append("authToken",this.getAuthToken());
      return this._http.get('url', {headers:headers})
                .map(this.parseData)
    }

    private parseData(res: Response) {
        return res.json || [];
    }
```

From Backend side :

```
@Path("/path")
@GET

public Response getData() {
  //retrive data from db and call required service to process
  return Response.ok(result)
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT")
                .status(Status.OK).build();
}
```

Now, when service method is called in angular, I am getting error.

Request Header details:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authtoken,content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8085
Origin:http://localhost:3000
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
```

Response is :

```
Authentication failed - Token absent
```

Console error :

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8085/*url* 401 (Unauthorized)

Failed to load http://localhost:8085/*url*: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

I am not able to figure out how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using JWT token ?

Comment: It will be better to keep an `HttpInterceptor` and add the tokens there if you have to do it in every service.

Comment: @NaveenYadav have you figured out if it's an issue of angular or backend? Try sending request through postman. If the request is failing through postman also, then you may need to debug your backend code first.

Comment: @theLearner Yes, I had tested the backend service using postman, its working fine.

Comment: In that case, I guess the below solutions won't solve your problem because since your backend is working(from postman request) with header `authToken`. Changing it to `Bearer`(although this is standard and you should use) won't make the issue go away. I am suspecting this to be a CORS issue.

Comment: Yes, may be it is a CORS error, but in console the http error code is 401.

Comment: @NaveenYadav You can give a try to my answer below

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JWT with 'Bearer' authentication:

```
getDataFromBackend() 
{
    return this._http.get('url', this.getAuthHeader(true)).map(this.parseData)
}

private parseData(res: Response) 
{
    return res.json || [];
}

private getAuthHeader(includeJsonContentType?: boolean): RequestOptions
{
  let headers = new Headers({
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.getAuthToken() });

  if (includeJsonContentType)
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

  headers.append("Accept", "application/vnd.iman.v01+json, application/json, text/plain, */*");
  headers.append("App-Version", "01");

  return new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment, this seems a CORS issue.

You can workaround this problem by using a filter and appending appropriate headers to your response like this:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)

public class CustomCorsFilter implements Filter {

@Resource
    private Environment environment;    

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res, final FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                environment.getProperty("cors.request.allowed-origin"));
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                environment.getProperty("cors.request.allowed-methods"));
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                environment.getProperty("cors.request.allowed-headers"));
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", environment.getProperty("cors.request.max-age"));
        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(((HttpServletRequest) req).getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);    
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO destroy logic (if any) to be here.
    }

    @Override
    public void init(final FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        // TODO init logic (if any) to be here.
    }
}
```

I am assuming you are keeping the value for these headers in application.properties like this:

```
cors.request.allowed-origin=*
cors.request.allowed-methods=POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH
cors.request.allowed-headers=Authorization, Content-Type
cors.request.max-age=3600
```

Otherwise you can directly put these values in your code instead of obtaining them from environment.

**Pay close attention to** `cors.request.allowed-headers`.
You need to specify the header name exactly to be the one you would be using from your client side.
You can set it to Authorization / myAuthToken or any other name but the standard is to use `Authorization`

Comment: This filter is already there and working fine. One thing I concluded from debugging is, in headers(angular) I am setting the key for token as 'authToken' but in request 'authtoken' is being appended (refer Request Header in question). In filters we are looking for request-header as 'authToken'. Can this be my issue?

Comment: do you mean to ask is there is a difference between `headers.set` and `headers.append`?